# Keep classes that use reflection Android Proguard

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-proguard

I'm trying to use this class. It works fine on debug builds but It never works on release builds. I know that proguard removes it, so the question is How to keep that class?

```
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi 
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated 
                //noinspection RestrictedApi 
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This did the trick for me.

```
# Bottom Navigation Helper
-keep class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView{ *; }
-keep class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView{ *; }
```

Comment: You can also use the Android support annotation `@Keep` instead of modifying proguard config files.

Comment: What does `{*;}` do?

Comment: It'll stop changing the constructor names and function name inside BottomNavigationItemView class.. @Mr.Nacho

Answer (score 0):

to keep the class

```
-keep class com.example.** { *; }
```

to keep the atrribute,

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.** { <fields>; }
```

Comment: I tried this with no luck 

# Bottom Navigation Helper
-keep  class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView{ *; }
-keep  class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView{ *; }
-keep class com.maachla.android.utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.maachla.android.utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper{ *; }

Comment: instead of doing it for every class, you can do -keep class com.maachla.android.utils.** { *; }

Comment: I tried it it didn't work. 
I think the problem is in the support library classes